# Match the string starting with initials followed by a valid alphabetic string - Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a string that starts with (Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.|Dr.|Er.) followed by any string [a-zA-Z] but somehow it is also passing it for "Er.Dr.".

Let me know what I am doing wrong with the regular expression here.

```
var input = [
    {str: "Mr.X", expectedValue: true},
    {str: "Mrs.Y", expectedValue: true},
    {str: "Dr#Joseph", expectedValue: false},
    {str: "Er .Abc", expectedValue: false},
    {str: "Er.Dr.", expectedValue: false},
    {str: "Er.Abc", expectedValue: true}
];

var re = /^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\.+[A-Za-z]/;

input.forEach(x => {
    var answer;
    var matchStr;
    answer = re.test(x.str);
    matchStr = x.expectedValue === answer ? "MATCH" : "NO MATCH";
    console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    console.log(`"${x.str}" | Expected Output: ${x.expectedValue} | My Output: ${answer} | ${matchStr}`);
    console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
})
```

**Output -**

[image: Regex 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the regular expression a bit, from

```
/^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\.+[A-Za-z]/
```

to

```
/^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\.[A-Za-z]+$/
```

without multiple `.` and checking the letters until the end of the string.

```js
var input = [
    {str: "Mr.X", expectedValue: true},
    {str: "Mrs.Y", expectedValue: true},
    {str: "Dr#Joseph", expectedValue: false},
    {str: "Er .Abc", expectedValue: false},
    {str: "Er.Dr.", expectedValue: false},
    {str: "Er.Abc", expectedValue: true}
];

var re = /^(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\.[A-Za-z]+$/;

input.forEach(x => {
    var answer;
    var matchStr;
    answer = re.test(x.str);
    matchStr = x.expectedValue === answer ? "MATCH" : "NO MATCH";
    console.log(`"${x.str}" | Expected Output: ${x.expectedValue} | My Output: ${answer} | ${matchStr}`);
})
```

Comment: this RegEx will return true for this input "Er.Dr.", which is not wrong but how can this RegEx be modified to return false for this kind of input?

Comment: @samee, you could try yourself and if you do not get it, you could as a question with your try.

Comment: already tried and got this one working /^[Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er]+([\.\-]?[a-zA-z]+)?$/

Comment: please have a look to the function of `[]` brackets. the order does not matter of the letters and `|` is looking for `|`, inside of brackets.